# Squid: Setup reverse proxy based on url path

Tags: proxy, reverse-proxy, squid, static-routes

I'm currently trying to [bypass browser security](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56928654/782034), by hosting a static html page under all (external) domains.

**e.g.**

> ```
> Given a webpage hosted at http://myinternalserver/mypage.html
> When I request https://www.google.com/mypage.html via the proxy
> Then my webpage is displayed.
> ```

I've added the following snippet to my `squid.conf`, however the content isn't being intercepted (I get `404 Not Found` from target site).

#### What am I doing wrong?

***squid.conf***

```
# reverse proxy /mypage* requests to internal server
acl myrule urlpath_regex ^/mypage

cache_peer myinternalserver parent 80 0 no-query originserver name=server1 
cache_peer_access server1 allow myrule 
cache_peer_access server1 deny all
```

I've tried turning on [detailed logging](https://wiki.squid-cache.org/SquidFaq/SquidAcl#I_set_up_my_access_controls.2C_but_they_don.27t_work.21__why.3F), but I can't see `myrule` being checked (it's never logged). Is the ACL not being picked up? Do I have to enable `urlpath_regex`? Is is a compile option for Squid?

**Squid Version**

- [Squid Cache: Version 3.5.27](https://hub.docker.com/r/alatas/squid-alpine-ssl/tags)

**Related:**

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/408913/94933

**Update:**

I found (and commented out) the following line - so now the reverse proxy works for `HTTP` requests. Just need to get it working with `HTTPS`...

```
# vvv WARNING: THIS WILL SKIP cache_peer DIRECTIVES vvv
# always_direct allow all
```

---

Full disclosure, I've also posted in [unix.stackexchange.com](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/529081/squid-setup-reverse-proxy-based-on-url-path) - will close whichever receives the least attention.